# Why does "volatile" demand declare-define consistency only from arrays?

Tags: c, compilation, linker, declaration

Given the declaration:

```
extern foo bar;
```

And, in another file, the definition:

```
volatile foo bar = ...
```

I get an error that the definition and declaration are incompatible, which disappears if I add *volatile* to the declaration or remove it from the definition.

But that's only if `foo` is an array type, scalar types get along fine with the inconsistency.

I tried it in three different compilers. Does anyone know a reason for this?

Comment: Idea: Rather than say two or three different compilers, post a list of compilers.  Post the example definition and declaration used with/without `volatile`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having mismatched qualifiers(*const*, *volatile*, *restrict*) for either a scalar or array should be [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Declarations that refer to the same object should have compatible types otherwise we have undefined behavior, we can see this from the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.2.7` *Compatible type and composite type*

> All declarations that refer to the same object or function shall have
>   compatible type; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

and we can see that a definition is also a declaration from `6.7` *Declarations*:

> A definition of an identifier is a declaration for that identifier
>   that

and we can see from `6.7.3` *Type qualifiers* that it means type qualifiers must match:

> For two qualified types to be compatible, both shall have the
>   identically qualified version of a compatible type; the order of type
>   qualifiers within a list of specifiers or qualifiers does not affect
>   the specified type.

Answer (score 2):

Strict rules of type compatibility require your declarations to have identical cv-qualifications. I.e. it is not supposed to work even for non-array types. The fact that your compiler allows it to slip through is an implementation-specific quirk of your compiler.

However, one can make an educated guess that the underlying reason for the array-specific behavior is one well-known property of arrays: it is not possible to apply cv-qualifiers to the array itself; any cv-qualifiers applied to array type "fall through" and apply to the individual array elements instead.

For example, this is the reason the following code fails to compile

```
typedef int A[10];
...
A a;
const A *p = &a;
```

Note that if `A` is not an array type, then the code is valid. But of `A` is an array (as in the above example), the initialization immediately becomes a constraint violation from standard C point of view. The initialization shall not compile. `const A *` is `const int (*)[10]`, and in C `const int (*)[10]` is not compatible with `int (*)[10]`.

In your example, the same compatibility logic (or a variation thereof) is probably used by the compiler when matching declarations to definitions, except that you used `volatile` instead of `const`. You can probably reproduce the same result with `const`.